# IDLE Python - How to make it so when a key is pressed, the loop runs?

Tags: python

I have made a macro and I want it so when I run the py file, nothing happens, but when I click a certain key, the if statement runs the while loop, and when I click that key again, the script pauses.

```
import time
import keyboard

time.sleep(3)

while True:
    try:
        #slot-1
        pyautogui.press('2')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #slot-2
        pyautogui.press('3')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #slot-3
        pyautogui.press('4')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #slot-4
        pyautogui.press('5')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
            print('Ending Loop')
            break
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

For starting the loop you can use input() (Press return / enter to directly start)

For finishing it press ctrl + c and catch KeyboardInterrupt exception

```
import time
import keyboard

time.sleep(3)

# press enter to start
input()

# press ctrl + c to finish
while True:
    try:
        #slot-1
        pyautogui.press('2')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #slot-2
        pyautogui.press('3')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #slot-3
        pyautogui.press('4')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #slot-4
        pyautogui.press('5')
        pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
            print('Ending Loop')
            break
    except Exception as e:
        if e == KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('script stopped by user')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a mix of threading and used global variables in order to solve your problem. I also had to resort to the pynput module instead of "keyboard". Although this is a slight workaround, the best solution in your scenario would be the use of "async" (asynchronous programming) in order to prevent the issue of blocking while loops. These are loops which will not allow any other part of your program to run. This means our program will not be able to detect key presses once it is inside a while loop. I have not used async simply because I am not familiar with its syntax and did not want to make this answer more complicated than it should be.

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import threading
time.sleep(3)

closed = False

def begin_clicks():
    global closed
    while True:
        print(closed)
        if closed:
            break
        try:
            #slot-12
            pyautogui.press('2')
            pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            #slot-2
            pyautogui.press('3')
            pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            #slot-33
            pyautogui.press('4')
            pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            #slot-4
            pyautogui.press('5')
            pyautogui.click(button= 'left', clicks=1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
    
        except:
            pass

thread = None

def on_press(key):
    global closed
    if str(key)[1] == "p":
        closed = False
        threading.Thread(target=begin_clicks).start()
    elif key == Key.alt:
        closed = True
        
        
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: No worries @DrMeyhem! Let me know if you need further support